# SHA1 Plain text? C#.NET

Tags: c#, sha1

I am using C# and calculating SHA1 for a string. My question is that will this always produce plain text 0-1 and A-Z ? Or it will produce has with special characters too ? I mean is ComputeHash function here will return always plain text ?

```
SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
string receivedValue = BitConverter.ToString(sha1.ComputeHash(to_be_hash)).Replace("-", "");
```

Not sure but I think it should generate special character only if its converted to Base 64 .

Comment: what type is `to_be_hash`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a hex string, so only 0-9 and A-F.

Actually it's just a byte array, but you use the `string BitConverter.ToString(byte[])` method to turn it into a hex-string in pairs of two separated by a - (dash).

Hexadecimal only contains: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, C, D, E, F. 16 options, a pair of two of those will represent a single byte (16*16 = 2^8 = 256, is a single byte).

Comment: You mean output of C# function ComputeHash is always HEX string ?

Comment: No the output is actually a `byte[]`, but you convert it to a hex string, so it's always safe. I extended the answer.

Comment: Here's the prototype:  public byte[] ComputeHash(
 byte[] buffer
)

Comment: Sorry for one more confirmation as working on something very sensitive : BitConverter.ToString() this is the thing that converts it to HEX string you mean ?

Comment: Yes it is :) Also I'll extend it a little bit, the answer. Done

Comment: ASCII is a 7-bit encoding, so `Encoding.ASCII.GetString` will convert every byte >= 0x80 to '?'; this will destroy (on average) half of the information in the hash result.

Comment: `string str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(computeHashResultHere);` that line is completely broken.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter. But what would you downvote if not incorrect answers? And that silent data loss can cause subtle bugs.

Answer (score 24):

The hashing API itself returns a `byte[]` containing an arbitrary 20 byte sequence.

You need to convert it to string yourself. Using Hex or Base64 as encodings are popular choices.

`BitConverter.ToString()` converts the string to hex with bytes delimited by `-`. Since you then remove the `-`s you end up with a 40 character hex string (`0`-`9`, `A`-`F`), which is a subset of alphanumeric chars.

So your code will always return an alphanumeric string, even though `SHA-1` doesn't.

```
SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(to_be_hash)
string delimitedHexHash = BitConverter.ToString(hash);
string hexHash = delimitedHexHash.Replace("-", "");
```