# Create login with hashed password in asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, codeigniter, hash

I have `MySQL` database in which data comes from `codeigniter`, hence in the user table the password is stored in hashes. I have to make a panel in asp.net using this database. The problem is that whenever I return the password, it shows the hashes. How do I authenticate the user at login?

### What have i tried

I tried to decrypt the password with the method given at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Security.Cryptography.MD5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I googled a lot for this. Is it possible to convert hash into a string? One of my passwords is
`7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b` In real it is 123456. How can I decrypt this? I tried to use [Asp.Net Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/eeyk640h%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), but it did not succeed. I need to decrypt the password because I have to use it in the change password form.

Comment: Hashed Password can not be decrypt only an Encrypted password can be decrypt to the correct value

Comment: are you sure that the data that comes from codeigniter is encrypted with md5 (it could be sh1)? and is the key when encrypting from .net the same?

Comment: what type of encryption you have used to get that hash ? got its, its sha1. most of the sites use reset password and not `change password` if you want change password. you need to `encrypt password where reversible is possible`

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee I know hashed password is forward only and can not be decrypted. Is there any way to compare a textbox value with orignal sreing of hash

Comment: @YuliamChandra I am not sure and as i written in question MD5 is not working.

Comment: You don't need to get the real value. To check whether the password matches or not, you need to recalculate the hash and compare that to your stored hash

Comment: Check with SHA1, where as mostly .net developers prefer MD5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hashed Password** can not be **decrypt**, only an **Encrypted** password can be decrypt to the correct value.

**To solve your issue:**

You need to check by **which technique is used to Hash the password** while strong it in Database like MD5 or SHA1 etc.

Then perform the same hashing either in your server or I would rather **choose/suggest Javascript** (In that manner your password hashing will actually serve the purpose also to enhance the security you can add a salt key, so that the hashed password is also not open to anyone while travelling) and then match the Hashed textbox value with the stored Hashed value.

**Sample for your Problem:**

`String password = "123456";`

**Outputs:**

```
Original text   123456
Original bytes  31:32:33:34:35:36 (length=6)
Adler32 042e0136
CRC32   0972d361
Haval   1d8071d4a59f25a2a92a9a4844ba1e05
MD2 d4541250b586296fcce5dea4463ae17f
MD4 585028aa0f794af812ee3be8804eb14a
MD5 e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e
RipeMD128   d6d56cab46e0f3af2c756289f2b447e0
RipeMD160   d8913df37b24c97f28f840114d05bd110dbb2e44
SHA-1   7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b
SHA-256 8d969eef6ecad3c29a3a629280e686cf0c3f5d5a86aff3ca12020c923adc6c92
SHA-384 0a989ebc4a77b56a6e2bb7b19d995d185ce44090c13e2984b7ecc6d446d4b61ea9991b76a4c2f04b1b4d244841449454
SHA-512 ba3253876aed6bc22d4a6ff53d8406c6ad864195ed144ab5c87621b6c233b548baeae6956df346ec8c17f5ea10f35ee3cbc514797ed7ddd3145464e2a0bab413
Tiger   5b2715f7cb7488ce2deb8544f0aa91b6f0eec76fb3b74265
Whirlpool   f30d7ab2a27f7e64da1a506c4ed99e1d89b3592d98376e3eeb28668552ab72697998f05a16007df8d72eb4f0e1ad2c2b1f47f3e86c4267f64e1314e616e002a1
```

Here you can see the `SHA-1 7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b` is the given/desired output by you.

**[Reference for String to Hash](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm?text=123456)**

Hope it helps.

Comment: do you know default hashing technique of codeigniter without using any salt. or it use any salt while hashing?

Comment: FIrst time Hash never use a Salt
as far as Encryption technique is concerned
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/encryption.html
I think this doc says it uses SHA1

Comment: I check it with SHA1, SHA256 and MD5 but hash is coming differant?

Comment: ok what is the password 123456?
and the Hashed is 7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b right?

Comment: check my edited answer, It is `SHA-1 7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b`

Comment: thanks, i converted it by http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1(v=vs.110).aspx method may be i was wrong i'll check it.

Comment: Hope, it will solve, SHA1 should serve your purpose.

Comment: Thanks a lot Arjit. it's exactly what i want. But how can i convert a text to sha-1 in asp.net c#. i returns bytes from msdn method and convert them to string but doesn't work

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/628715/How-to-Convert-Hashcode-SHA-to-string

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340539/sha1-plain-text-c-net

These 2 links will help you through