# MD5 hashing in windowsphone 8

Tags: c#, hash, windows-phone, md5

Hay there i'm trying to hash a string to MD5 in windows phone ... but when i call the MD5 class i get the following error

> **The type or namespace name 'MD5' could not be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)**

PS: i have used the System.Security.Cryptography name space
so how can i use the MD5 hash in the windows phone ?
here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace FluoraPin
{
    class HASHING
    {
        public static string GetMd5Hash(MD5 md5Hash, string input)
        {

            // Convert the input string to a byte array and compute the hash. 
            byte[] data = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));

            // Create a new Stringbuilder to collect the bytes 
            // and create a string.
            StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            // Loop through each byte of the hashed data  
            // and format each one as a hexadecimal string. 
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
            }

            // Return the hexadecimal string. 
            return sBuilder.ToString();
        }

        // t verify md5 hashing
        private bool VerifyMd5Hash(MD5 md5Hash, string input, string hash)
        {
            // Hash the input. 
            string hashOfInput = GetMd5Hash(md5Hash, input);

            // Create a StringComparer an compare the hashes.
            StringComparer comparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;

            if (0 == comparer.Compare(hashOfInput, hash))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer but: I'm assuming you know that MD5 is broken?

Comment: nooop i didn't know that !! thanks what do u suggest ?

Comment: Use [SHA-256](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-256), which is available for Windows Phone 7 and 8 through the [`SHA526Managed` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.security.cryptography.sha256managed(v=vs.105).aspx). An [answer to another SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1756222/1810429) provides an example of how to hash with `SHA256Managed` in C#.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is right in the error:

> The type or namespace name 'MD5' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

`MD5` is not a class in the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace for Windows Phone.  See [MSDN's `System.Security.Cryptography` page for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/System.Security.Cryptography%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for confirmation.

Contrast this with [MSDN's general `System.Security.Cryptography` page,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/System.Security.Cryptography%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) which lists `MD5` as a class in the namespace.

Having said this, you should really use [SHA-256](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-256) or higher instead of MD5 or SHA-1 hashing.

SHA-256 hashing is available for Windows Phone 7 and 8 through the `SHA256Managed` class - in the `Security.Security.Cryptography` namespace you are already using.  For an example of how to use `SHA256Managed`, see an [answer to a related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1756222/1810429).

Comment: But I need MD5 to sign API query

Comment: This is a very obvious answer. How bout trying to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

This person has an implementation of MD5 hashing in C# that can be used for WP8:

http://upadhyayjitesh.blogspot.com/2013/01/windows-phone-md5-hash-conversion.html

Answer (score 0):

You could add Bouncy Castle as a NuGet package to your project. It supports MD5 hashing (and much more encryption algorithms). See its [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/BouncyCastle/) page for more details. Or its project page "[The Legion of the Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/)"

Answer (score -4):

I haven't tested your solution but I found a solution that works fine for me.

`using System.Security.Cryptography;`

```
class MD5Hash
{
    public String getHash(String input)
    {
        MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
        byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
        byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
            sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("x2"));

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public Boolean VerifyHash(String input, String hash)
    {
        String hashOfInput = getHash(input);

        StringComparer comparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;

        if (0 == comparer.Compare(hashOfInput, hash))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

This will hash your String, no errors at all.

Also, the error you are getting, check that you are not compiling a .Net version that include the text "Client Profile".

I am new to this so If I have got this completely wrong then I'm sorry could you be a bit more specific with you question.

Comment: System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 is not available on windows phone